# Javascript converting text from greek to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, leaflet, shapefile

I am attempting to help my teacher convert a Greek textbook into an online application.  Part of this includes taking a Shapefile ( draws polygons on maps, along with descriptions of the polygons. )  and mapping everything on this map.  I cannot directly access the part of the shapefile file that has the data I need to convert due to it being in hexadecimal.
Anyways,  here is the code that I am printing to my console.

```
 console.log((arr[1][i]['PERIOD']);
```

"arr" is the data array that contains all of the properties that I want to convert from Greek into UTF-8. I am only printing "PERIOD", rather than the 12 other propierties that are associated with the array.

When I run my page, the console returns several variations of text(as there exist several periods.) Here is an example of the text it returns.

```
ÎÏÏÎ±ÏÎºÎ®, ÎÎ»Î±ÏÎ¹ÎºÎ®, ÎÎ»Î»Î·Î½Î¹ÏÏÎ¹ÎºÎ®
Î¡ÏÎ¼Î±ÏÎºÎ®
ÎÎ¸ÏÎ¼Î±Î½Î¹ÎºÎ®
Î¥ÏÏÎµÏÎ¿Î²ÏÎ¶Î±Î½ÏÎ¹Î½Î®
```

Believe it or not, but this is not Greek text.  So I snooped around and found this function to convert to utf-8:

```
function encode_utf8( s ){
return  unescape(encodeURI( s ));
}
```

When I add this function to my console.log, this is what I get:

```
ÃÂ¡ÃÂÃÂ¼ÃÂ±ÃÂÃÂºÃÂ®
ÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂ¼ÃÂ±ÃÂ½ÃÂ¹ÃÂºÃÂ®
ÃÂ¥ÃÂÃÂÃÂµÃÂÃÂ¿ÃÂ²ÃÂÃÂ¶ÃÂ±ÃÂ½ÃÂÃÂ¹ÃÂ½ÃÂ®
ÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂÃÂ¼ÃÂ±ÃÂ½ÃÂ¹ÃÂºÃÂ®
```

I am not 100% positive but I think that the text I am trying to convert is currently in ISO-8859-7.

Any help with this would be amazing. 

Thank you.

Comment: Greek is a language; UTF-8 is an encoding (of Unicode). It looks like what you really want is to decode ISO 8859-7 (to Unicode text).

Comment: Show us how you are reading in the shapefile (or whatever the data comes from). That's where your problem lies, and that's where you can fix the encoding.

Comment: You should give us 1. an extract from the "hex file", 2. how you're loading this hex file into your _JavaScript_ 3. how you're converting the data you've loaded to _String_

Answer (score 0):

You quite easily can build a map of the bytes of one char set to another (although it can get tedious)

Assuming [*ISO 8859-7*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) which is only `256` bytes long so not too difficult,

```
function genCharMap() { // ISO 8859-7 to Unicode
    var map = [], i, j, str;
    map.length = 256;
    map[0] = 0; // fill in 0
    str = '\u2018\u2019\u00a3\u20ac\u20af\u00a6\u00a7\u00a8\u00a9\u037a\u00ab\u00ac\u00ad\u00ae\u2015\u00b0\u00b1\u00b2\u00b3\u0384\u0385\u0386\u00b7\u0388\u0389\u038a\u00bb\u038c\u00bd\u038e';
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) // fill in 0xA1 to 0xBE
        map[0xA1 + i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) // fill in blanks
        if (i in map) j = map[i] - i;
        else map[i] = j + i;
    return map;
}
```

Now you can apply this transformation to your **bytes**

```
var byteArr = [0xC1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xE4], // Αβγδ
    str_out = '',
    i,
    map = genCharMap();

for (i = 0; i < byteArr.length; ++i) {
    str_out += String.fromCharCode(
        map[byteArr[i]]
    );
}

str_out; // "Αβγδ"
```

---

If you're re-writing this code for a charset with *"combining chars"* it may be safer to swap the *str* I used in `genCharMap` for an *Array* of numbers instead.